# Can't seem to include any cpp file other than main.cpp when using template class

Tags: c++, templates

I decided to cut the necessary code down to the bare minimum needed to display this error. I have an STL list wrapper template class that exists in hc_list.h file. The entire code is below:

```
// hc_list.h file
#ifndef HC_LIST_H
#define HC_LIST_H

#include <cstdlib>
#include <list>

template <typename T>
class hcList
{
    private:
    std::list<T> selfList ; // a single internal STL list to hold the values

    public:
    hcList(void) {} ;
    ~hcList(void){} ;
    // The error occurs on the line below
    template <typename U> friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &, const hcList<U> &) ;
} ;
#endif // HC_LIST_H
```

This code is included in the main.cpp file, where the main function is below:

```
// main.cpp file
#include <iostream>
#include "hc_list.h"
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Begin Test" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code, when entered into a CodeBlocks project will compile as is with 0 errors or warnings. However, then I include another cpp file and attempt to include the list header, like the following:

```
// anyNamedFile.cpp file
#include "hc_list.h"
```

When I include any cpp file into the project, I get a compiler error:

```
error: expected initializer before '&' token
```

I do not understand what I am doing wrong, and could really use some help.

Comment: Does your main actually instantiate an `hcVector`? Could you show the definition of your `operator<<`?

Comment: nope. My main just outputs "Begin Test" and then returns 0.

Comment: Then it's not instantiating the template, and the template code isn't fully compiled. Please post the relevant code, namely the `operator<<` definition.

Comment: Added both chunks of code as requested.

Comment: Where is the error generated? The code you posted is incomplete/not compilable, but looks fine.

Comment: The error occurs on the line in hcVector.h where I declare the output operator.

Comment: Then there's something wrong in that header between the template class declaration and that operator definition.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm pretty sure it's more of a templating or linking error, considering the hcVector class compiles and runs fine on its own and the inclusion of the cpp file causes this issue.

Comment: It's a **syntax** error (or something close to that). Way before anything like linking is every going to happen. Yes, its related to something about templates apparently, but there's a problem in code you're not showing.

Comment: I've never seen a compiler error that didn't print a line number before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your header file uses `std::ostream`, (just before an `&`) but does not include any header which might declare it.

Try adding

```
#include <iosfwd>
```

in your header.

Comment: Thank you very much. I added the code to the paired down example I posted and the compiler error has disappeared. However, it appears as though including this file causes a problem with any strings being output, and I get a lot of: error: 'endl' is not a member of 'std'

Comment: Including `<iosfwd>` allows you to use streams in declarations, and is all you need in your header. To actually do I/O, your .cpp files should include `<ostream>` and possibly other headers as well.

Comment: Perhaps this is because I have a fundamentally incorrect understanding of includes. the tutorials I have been reading have all indicated that I just include <cstdlib> and all of these sub-libraries should already be included in the std namespace. Why do I need to go and re-specify each section? Isn't that a little like stating "I want to include the entire dictionary" then stating "I also want to include all the M and C letters too?"

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what `<cstdlib>` does; it doesn't include all the other C++ headers. In fact it's a fairly obscure header. There has been some discussion of having a C++ header that includes all the other headers, but at the moment there is no such beast. So you just have to include all the relevant ones (and learn which ones that is - which isn't actually as bad as perhaps it sounds).