# Include <iosfwd> appears to cause a namespace issue?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to understand why including iosfwd would cause output streams including standard strings not to work.

```
// hc_list.h file
#ifndef HC_LIST_H
#define HC_LIST_H

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iosfwd> // including this file makes the output operator throw errors
#include <list>

template <typename T>
class hcList
{
    private:
    std::list<T> selfList ; // a single internal STL list to hold the values

    public:
    hcList(void) {} ;
    ~hcList(void){} ;
    template <typename U> friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &, const hcList<U> &) ;
} ;

template <typename U>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const hcList<U> &outList)
{
    out << "test" << std::endl ; // this line throws two errors, stated below
    return out ;
}
#endif // HC_LIST_H
```

This code is included in the main.cpp file, where the main function is below:

```
// main.cpp file
#include <iostream>
#include "hc_list.h"
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Begin Test" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In order to actually utilize this code and generate the error, an empty cpp file is needed that includes the list header file.

```
// anyNamedFile.cpp file
#include "hc_list.h"
```

When I attempt to compile, I receive the following errors:

```
error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'out<< "test"'
error: 'endl' is not a part of 'std'
```

What is it in  that causes the std namespace to get screwed up and no longer allow me to output strings?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't seem to include any cpp file other than main.cpp when using template class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564627/cant-seem-to-include-any-cpp-file-other-than-main-cpp-when-using-template-class)

Comment: good catch, but actually I didn't intend to make this a duplicate. The answer you provided to me worked in the example, however generated what I considered to be a separate issue in my main project (not the paired down example code). While related in example, both questions stemmed back to my misunderstanding of <cstdlib>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems here. The first problem is that you are using `std::endl`, but that is defined in `<ostream>`, which is not included.

The second problem is that you are only including the header `<iosfwd>`, which forward declares many of the iostream types. Forward declaration lets the compiler know that the types *exist*. However, you are trying to use these types' *functionality*. Since you are doing that, you should include `<ostream>`, rather than `<iosfwd>`. `<ostream>` contains `std::endl`, so that should take care of everything.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it so thoroughly. I really appreciate the help.